# android transparent WebView on top of VideoView

Tags: android, webview, android-videoview, transparent

I have an Ionic project where I want to display a video, and on top of it the content of the cordova `WebView`. To have the transparent `WebView` on top of the video view, in a plugin I use:

```
webView.getView().setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
((ViewGroup) webView.getView()).bringToFront();
```

The `VideoView` is initialized and added in a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
FrameLayout containerView = (FrameLayout) cordova.getActivity().findViewById(1);

if (containerView == null) {
  containerView = new FrameLayout(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  containerView.setId(1);
  containerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

  FrameLayout.LayoutParams containerLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  cordova.getActivity().addContentView(containerView, containerLayoutParams);

  videoView = new VideoView(cordova.getActivity());
  videoView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  containerView.addView(videoView);

  MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
  player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
  player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  player.setOnErrorListener(this);

  final SurfaceHolder holder = videoView.getHolder();
  holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
  holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      player.setDisplay(holder);
      try {
        player.prepare();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      player.release();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
  });
}
```

I have tested this on Android 4.4.2 and it works great. I have then tested it on Android 5.1.1, and the `WebView` is not visible when the video is playing. But if I use Chrome to inspect it and hover the `<body>` for example (then the screen shows the overlay blue), then the elements within the html content appear. Also if I touch the screen then the content suddenly appear. So it seems it is a rendering issue when there is no interaction with the `WebView`, but as soon at is receives a touch or some kind of trigger then it appears.

I have also tried using Crosswalk, and it still works perfectly fine on 4.2.2, but only works when starting the app on 5.1.1 and then after first interaction it only works when touching the screen

Also I have set `<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff000000"/>` in `config.xml`, but that doesn't change the behavior.

Edit 1:
I've added a div with some transparent text in it, and put a simple infinite animation on it (that just changed the opacity from `.9` to `1`), and voila the elements within the `WebView` now appear on top of the video when playing. It's not perfect as sometimes the `WebView` content will "blink", but it does work. Still have no clue why though

Comment: Did you ever figure this layering out? I'm trying to do something similar and having trouble finding examples.

Comment: No, in the end I kept using the `animation` in css technic to trigger the "repaint" of the webview (see Edit 1)

Answer (score -1):

Replace code with below.

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

If you want to add webview on top of video view,
use application content layout and add webview in it as below.

```
FramlayoutLayout layout = (FramlayoutLayout )cordova.getActivity() findViewById(android.R.id.content);
layout.addview(your webview)
```

Comment: `Color.TRANSPARENT` is the same as `0x00000000`, it just means `0`. I am not sure I get what you mean by `layout.addview(your webview)`, as I am using the default cordova `WebView` and not a custom one, which is already added in the main content view, so I am not sure what this would change